# Delphi Associating and using file extensions

Tags: delphi, file-extension

i need my delphi program to open a .xcr file type which will be encrypted text. i want to assign my Delphi program as the default program to open this file when the user clicks on it. I've done some research and from what i can tell i need to use the registry object in Delphi to change the registry but i'm not too sure how to do that. How exactly would i assign this file extension to the program and more importantly how do i use this to run the decryption procedure in the program? Do i link the opening of the file from windows task manager to the procedure somehow?

Sorry for not making much sense but i don't really understand how i'm meant to do this.

Comment: Installer should do that. But if you insist, here is how to [register association](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6285850/8041231), `ParamStr(1)` can tell you then the name of the file which was opened.

Comment: This is explained in the documentation. Of course. Where did you look?

Comment: Read [Implementing a Custom File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521657.aspx) on MSDN, particularly the [File Types and File Associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144104.aspx) and [Guidelines for File Associations and Default Programs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872123.aspx) sections.

Comment: @Ken Rather than adding more dupes as comments, you can edit the list of duplicates and add them there.

Comment: @David: Thanks. Had never noticed the edit link there.