# State of the art way to register/unregister a file type with my own application for the current user in Windows10?

Tags: delphi, registry, file-association, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have found several methods to register a file type with my own application (double-clicking that file type in Windows Explorer looads that file in my application). Several are very old and seem to be deprecated, others are unclear and lack practical usage examples and thus are prone to misunderstandings.

1. @AndreasRejbrand has published an accepted solution here:
   [How to associate a program with a file type, but only for the current user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285791/how-to-associate-a-program-with-a-file-type-but-only-for-the-current-user)
   a) There is no complimentary way to UNREGISTER the file type.
   b) It is not clear what `'MyAppDataFile'` means.
   c) There are no practical usage examples.
2. The `DSiWin32` library contains the methods `DSiRegisterUserFileAssoc` and `DSiUnregisterUserFileAssoc`:
   a) `procedure DSiRegisterUserFileAssoc(const extension, progID, description, defaultIcon, openCommand: string);`
   aa) It is not clear what the `progID` parameter means.
   ab) It is not clear how to pass the `defaultIcon` parameter.
   ac) It is not clear how to pass the `openCommand` parameter.
   b) `procedure DSiUnregisterUserFileAssoc(const progID: string);`
   ba) It is not clear what the `progID` parameter means and how to format it.
   c) it would be nice to have a practical usage example.

BTW, this is the code from @AndreasRejbrand:

```
with TRegistry.Create do
  try
    RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    if OpenKey('\Software\Classes\.myfile', true) then
      WriteString('', 'MyAppDataFile');
    if OpenKey('\Software\Classes\MyAppDataFile', true) then
      WriteString('', 'My Very Own Text File Type');
    if OpenKey('\Software\Classes\MyAppDataFile\DefaultIcon', true) then
      WriteString('', 'C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe');
    if OpenKey('\Software\Classes\MyAppDataFile\shell\open\command', true) then
      WriteString('', 'C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe "%1"');
  finally
    Free;
  end;
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, 0, 0);
```

Can anyone provide CLEAR "fool-proof" practical usage examples for both approaches? Which one is better?

EDIT: With "practical USAGE examples" I mean: A procedure/function with example parameters.

Comment: Isn't this documented over on MSDN?

Comment: 1a) The opposite of creating registry keys is to delete them, no? b) That's just an internal name for the file type. Could be `ContosoRichTextFile`, `LitwareVideoFile`, or `SuperappSettingsFile`. Or `User1580348StarTrekSimulatorStarshipModelFile`. It only has to be unique. c) Isn't my code snippet and its associated description a practical example? :) Still, that is an old approach. Probably the "state of the art" approach is more involved.

Comment: I think the official state-of-the-art approach is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/customizing-file-types-bumper

Comment: Suppose you have created a file format for a starship model for your Star Trek simulator. Then you may want to use the `.starship` extension for it, so the first key is `.starship` and you can use the identifier `user1580348starship`. Then you give it a description, `Starship model`, say, and you point out the icon to be used for such files as well as the application that should open them when double-clicked. Pretty straight-forward, isn't it?

Comment: "Which one is better?" They are exactly the same. If you look at the source code for `DSiRegisterUserFileAssoc`, you see that it does precisely the same thing as my code. https://github.com/gabr42/OmniThreadLibrary/blob/106ef82fcac01f4f27077acbdefe9c7e057c341e/src/DSiWin32.pas#L3195

Comment: If you want to see examples of file type registry entries, you can look in your own registry (Win+R, `regedit`, Enter).

Comment: Remove only progid to unregister, that's what MS suggests. You save yourself the effort of checking if the extensions still point to your progid or if another program has taken over.

Comment: The way to set up a file association in File Explorer is to right-click and select Open With... then check the box that says "Always use this app". If you want to break the file association, it's kind of odd. You want to make a copy of any EXE and then right-click the data file and say to open it with THE COPIED EXE "always". Do it for all file extensions you want to disassociate. Then delete that copied EXE file. That's going to update the registry entries for the selected extensions. They're not "deleted" so much as "disassociated" from an app that opens them.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That's what `DSiUnregisterUserFileAssoc` apparently does: `DSiKillRegistry('\Software\Classes\' + progID, HKEY_CURRENT_USER);`

Comment: When I double-click a .TXT file in Windows File Explorer then it opens in Notepad. But in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.txt` I find no reference to Notepad: There is only an `OpenWithList` that is totally different from what I see when I invoke the 'Open with' sub-menu of a .TXT file in File Explorer. I have also looked at the `\Software\Classes\.txt` keys of the other Registry roots, but I did not find any reference to Notepad. So how would it work when I try to register a new text file format (e.g. .MyCustomText) for Notepad following the code of @AndreasRejbrand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what the OP is actually asking, but in the comments there are a few requests for clarifications and I am not able to fit such explanations in comments, so instead I create a (possibly temporary) CW answer here.

Suppose you want all files with extension `.stext` to be called `Super Text File` in Explorer, be opened with `C:\Program Files\Super Editor\superedit.exe`, and have the icon `C:\Program Files\Super Editor\docicon.ico`, then you would use the following code:

```pascal
with TRegistry.Create do
  try
    RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    if OpenKey('\Software\Classes\.stext', true) then
      WriteString('', 'SuperTextFile');
    if OpenKey('\Software\Classes\SuperTextFile', true) then
      WriteString('', 'Super Text File');
    if OpenKey('\Software\Classes\SuperTextFile\DefaultIcon', true) then
      WriteString('', 'C:\Program Files\Super Editor\docicon.ico');
    if OpenKey('\Software\Classes\SuperTextFile\shell\open\command', true) then
      WriteString('', '"C:\Program Files\Super Editor\superedit.exe" "%1"');
  finally
    Free;
  end;
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, 0, 0);
```

The `SuperTextFile` string works as a connection between the file extension part and the file type part. You could call it `jmkrfnjk` if you like instead.

If, instead, you want to open the files in Notepad, use the path to `notepad.exe` instead in the last `WriteString`.

This might not be the most sophisticated approach (probably it is the Win 9x approach), but it still works, doesn't it? And I would be surprised if it will not continue to be valid for the entire future of the Win32 desktop platform.

The **DSiRegisterUserFileAssoc** routine does exactly [the same thing](https://github.com/gabr42/OmniThreadLibrary/blob/106ef82fcac01f4f27077acbdefe9c7e057c341e/src/DSiWin32.pas#L3195) as the code above, so both methods are exactly equivalent.

For all details on the state of the art, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/customizing-file-types-bumper).

Comment: `Winapi.ShlObj.SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, 0, 0);` does not work. The last two parameters need to be `nil`: `Winapi.ShlObj.SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, nil, nil);`

Comment: With the default compiler settings, it works and has the exact same behaviour. But you are right that `nil` is more semantically accurate.

Comment: What do you mean by "default compiler settings"? I am not aware of having installed special compiler settings. My Delphi IDE is 10.4.2 in Windows 10 x64. The project is a 32-bit VCL Application created by the IDE with File->New->Windows VCL Application Delphi.

Comment: Sorry, I have now realized that it was only a compiler WARNING. It does compile with `0` instead of `nil` too.

Comment: Using your method above, I have now associated the `.PNG` extension with my new graphics application. The icon association did work. The PNG file description BEFORE was `IrfanView PNG File`. It changed to my new description `PNG File` only after having rebooted Windows. However, when double-clicking a .PNG file in Windows, it is always opened in another image viewer, not in my graphics application. Of course, the exe path is enclosed in double quotes. And loading an image file in my application by passing the file as parameter of course does work.

Comment: A lot of programs compete for the `.PNG` extension. You would probably be more lucky with `.ujy-map` or something. Either you did something wrong, or you really do need to use a more fancy approach, at least for such common extensions, on Windows 10. Since I am using Windows 7, I cannot really test the behaviour on Windows 10.

Comment: Sorry, my error again: As I always use Directory Opus as File Explorer replacement, .PNG files double-clicked in Opus always open in the Opus viewer. When double-clicking .PNG files in Windows File Explorer, they open now correctly in my application.

Comment: In other words, `progID` is an IDENTIFIER that works as a LINK between Registry keys each referencing a property of a specific single file format. Is this definition correct?

Comment: Registering a File Format does work, both with @AndreasRejbrand's code and with `DSiRegisterUserFileAssoc`. BUT `DSiUnregisterUserFileAssoc` does NOT work, even in elevated mode (by starting the program as Administrator). So how can I UNREGISTER the registered File Format? (I suspect that the Microsoft apps registered under `.ico\OpenWithProgrids` stops the key from being removed?)

Comment: @user1580348: In what sense does it not work? Generally, file associations belong to the user, and the user can change them in any way at any time.

Comment: In what sense does it not work? Answer: The UGAICOFile progID key is not being deleted from the Registry (As it should)! And double-clicking an .ICO file in File Explorer still loads my app! Please look at my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67519443/how-to-unregister-a-file-format-for-my-application