# Add explorer context menu item for PDF files from delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, registry, contextmenu, explorer

I have my application written in Delphi XE that works with PDF files. Applicaiton is Win32. On start I would like to ensure that there is my item in explorer context menu for PDF files. I would like to be able to specify whether it should be added for active user only or for all users (with UAC I will need to restart with Admin privileges but thats ok).

I started with [How to associate a Delphi program with a file type, but only for the current user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285791/how-to-associate-a-delphi-program-with-a-file-type-but-only-for-the-current-use/6285850#6285850) and [How to add item to windows explorer content menu in delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797817/how-to-add-item-to-windows-explorer-content-menu-in-delphi) . I tested it with manual registry editing via regedit and it worked fine for "new" extensions. But for .pdf it is more complicated as it will be most probably already present in the registry.

On my PC the .pdf key is referencing AcroExch.Document . But adding shell/something subkey to the AcroExch.Document key is not working because it has CurVer subkey referencing to AcroExch.Document.7. However another PC with another verison of Acrobat had this names a little different. It is no problem for me to follow the CurVer reference but is that a correct approach? And what about situation where no PDF reader is installed, how should I name my keys so Acrobat won't overwrite them when installed?

But more pressing matter is in which root should I put my keys? [How to associate a Delphi program with a file type, but only for the current user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285791/how-to-associate-a-delphi-program-with-a-file-type-but-only-for-the-current-use/6285850#6285850) is mentioning HKLM (Local Machine) and HKCU (Current user). Its seems rather straightforward but I am unable to set values in HKLM from Delphi. Strangely I can create keys:

```
var reg:TRegistry;

key := '\Software\Classes\'+keyname+'\shell\'+name+'\command';
reg.CreateKey(key);
```

but I am getting Access Denied when trying to write the actual value:

```
reg.OpenKey(key,false);
reg.WriteString('',command);
```

I am getting the same Access Denied exception even on WinXP, no matter if the applicaiton is running as Admin (Win7), I even tried to set permissions (Everyone full control) for the key via regedit (I can edit the value via regedit without problems). I tried creating the registry with different access modes, all with no luck:

```
reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE or KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_ALL_ACCESS or KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
reg.Access := KEY_ALL_ACCESS;
reg.Access := KEY_WRITE or KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
reg.Access := KEY_ALL_ACCESS or KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
```

With HKCU everything works fine.

So I tried writing into HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and it works and actually puts the keys exactly where I want (into HKLM) if running as Admin. But according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475.aspx

> The HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (HKCR) key contains file name extension associations and COM class registration information such as ProgIDs, CLSIDs, and IIDs. It is primarily intended for compatibility with the registry in 16-bit Windows.

I do not like the note about the primary purpose being compatibile with 16-bit Windows. And the actual conditions where the changes will be written is more complicated than I would like.

So basically I have these questions:

- What is the advantage of using AcroExch.Document and CurVer instead of pointing directly to AcroExch.Document.7? And what are the "best manners" when adding my keys into this structure? What about the case when the .pdf is not yet associated with anything?
- Where should I put my keys and why I am not able to write into HKLM?

Edit:
The problem with Access Denied when writing to HKLM was caused by my error. I did use in previous code openKeyReadOnly and I did not notice that it will swtich the Access property to readonly for all subsequent calls.

Comment: I will add the example of the code. I do not check the return of openkey as it have to be present and the whole code is in try..catch  block...

Comment: `OpenKey` indicates failure by returning `False`. No amount of try/except is going to help you there. You simply must check the return value. Please provide SSCCE.

Comment: The code works in steps providing that either the key did already exist or it has been created in previous step. I have provided the code. I can provide the code of CheckContextMenuItem if needed but that one is working as expected so I did not want to clutter the question with that...

Comment: I'd like to see an SSCCE. Creating reg keys in HKLM works fine here. Please make the SSCCE. Your code is a bit of an abomination to be honest.

Comment: I did edit the original quuestion with SSCCE.

Comment: No. That is not an SSCCE. An SSCCE in this case would be a complete program of length around 20 lines. I would paste it into my IDE and run it directly. It requires a little more effort on your part.

Comment: I did include the whole unit and example how to call it.

Comment: This is a wall of code, not an SSCCE. You must make an effort. When you cut it down to 20 lines, I predict you will solve the problem yourself. The S in SSCCE stands for short.

Comment: You were right. When I re-wrote the code to just write one key to registry from scratch it worked. And it allowed me to find the problem in my code. I will edit the original question accordingly

Comment: If I were you, I'd just delete this question now. Unlikely for there to be much to be learned for the future visitor. Or at least edit the question to be only about the first of your two bullet points. I'm glad the SSCCE discipline did the trick. It often does!

Comment: I am deciding if I should delete the question or edit it to contain the first part. But that part is not that important. Actually there is a lesson that future visitor could find interesting but probably not with this subject... thanks for you help anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asked two separate questions. Since I know the answer to one and not the other, I'm going to answer just one. For future reference, I do recommend that you ask a single question at a time.

> Where should I put my keys?

You are correct in discerning that you should not use `HKCR`. The documentation for [`HKCR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475.aspx) says:

> Class registration and file name extension information is stored under
>   both the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_CURRENT_USER keys. The
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes key contains default settings that
>   can apply to all users on the local computer. The
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes key contains settings that apply
>   only to the interactive user. The HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key provides a
>   view of the registry that merges the information from these two
>   sources. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT also provides this merged view for
>   applications designed for previous versions of Windows.
>
> ....
>
> If you write keys to a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, the system stores
>   the information under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes. If you
>   write values to a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, and the key already
>   exists under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes, the system will store
>   the information there instead of under
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes.

So, it is reasonable to use `HKCR` for reading, but for writing you typically need to exert control over whether to write to `HKLM` or `HKCU`. And that means that you cannot write to `HKCR`.

So, write to `HKLM\Software\Classes` for machine-wide settings, and `HKCU\Software\Classes` for user-specific settings.

Note that in Windows 7 and later neither of these keys is [redirected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx) and so you do not need to worry about using `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`. However, in Vista and XP64, and the equivalent server editions, these keys are redirected and reflected. Which means that it might be prudent to use `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your other question, if Adobe is not installed yet then obviously the PDF keys will likely not exist in the Registry yet so you would have to create your own .pdf and ProgID keys so that you can attach your Shell command on it.  If Adobe is installed afterwards, it is likely going to wipe out your keys and replace them with its own, so you would have to recreate your Shell command within Adobe's key structure.  Your app can query the Registry to check for that condition periodically, such as at startup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do realize all that you say but I was hoping that Adobe won't wipe my keys if I create them in some "standard" way. I do not mind Adobe becoming the default action I just would like it to keep my item in the menu as it is one of the most frequent ways how users start my app.

Comment: The `.pdf` key has to be associated with Adobe's ProgID key (`AcroExch.Document`) in order for Adobe's own commands to take effect. A file extension can only be associated with one default ProgID at a time. Your ProgID key would still exist in the Registry, but the `.pdf` key would not invoke it by default anymore.  However, you could add your EXE/ProgID to the `OpenWithList`/`OpenWithProgIDs` list of the `.pdf` key, which might be enough for your needs.

Comment: That would allow your app to appear on the "Open With..." submenu of the file's popup Context Menu.

Comment: I will look into the Open With more deeply it sounds like a idea worth trying. I do understand that there can be only one ProgID at a time but I did hope that if I create it the way Adobe would like they could possible let me be...

Comment: The only way that would work is if you mimic Adobe's keys instead of creating your own keys. But think what would happen if a user decides to install a non-Adobe PDF viewer? They you are SOL.  Each app is supposed to create its own ProgID, not hijack someone else's. That is why I suggested you have your app monitor the Registry periodically and see if your command(s) exist in the current registered ProgID, and if not then add them as needed. Similar to how a web browser checks if it is the current default browser, and if not then prompts the user whether to change that or not.

Comment: I will do the periodic check, it is the most easy way. I just wanted to see if I am not missing something obvious. Actualy I did try to mimick the Adobe's keys and it still did wipe it and create new - but I tried it only once and maybe I did not mimic them 100%.